# D3.js looping through an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, d3.js

I'm trying to make a row of bars of equal height and width based on title. Having an array of 100 objects, each contains a *key* called ***results*** that itself and array of other 20 objects, so the end result must be a row of 2000 bars, however I'm only getting 20 bars:

[image: wrong output]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ekilja01/pen/RdJqGO

Data is an array of objects that have an array of objects called ***results***, in the following format:

```
0:
page: 1
results: Array(20)
0: {vote_count: 17968, id: 19995, video: false, vote_average: 7.4, title: "Avatar", …}
...
length: 20

1: {page: 2, total_results: 406130, total_pages: 20307, results: Array(20)}
2: {page: 3, total_results: 406130, total_pages: 20307, results: Array(20)}
```

Here is my approach:

```
d3.json('data.json').then(data => {

  console.log(data);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {


    //x and y domain
    xScale.domain(data[i].results.map(d => d.title));
    yScale.domain(data[i].results.map(d => d.original_title));

    svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(data[i].results)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .style('fill', 'red')
      .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
      .attr('height', 70)
      .attr('x', function (d) {
        return xScale(d.title);
      })
      .attr('y', function (d) {
        return yScale.bandwidth() + 175;
      });

  }
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, you append elements only the first time through the loop: there are 20 items in the data array, no rectangles in the svg, so all 20 items are entered. The second time there are 20 items in the data array, 20 rectangles in the svg, so the enter selection is empty, the new data is simply bound to the 20 existing rectangles.

As an alternative approach to the other answer, your data does not appear to be hierarchical, but you have a hierarchical structure. If your data structure is the same as your DOM structure, then this will be much more straightforward. Let's restructure your data a bit:

```
var combined = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  combined.push(...data[i].results);
}
```

Now our data is:

```
[
  {vote_count: 17968, id: 19995, video: false, vote_average: 7.4, title: "Avatar", …,}
  {...},
  {...},
  ...
```

And all objects that are to be mapped are in one array, one item in the array, one element to add to the chart. Now we can do a simple enter cycle:

```
svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(combined)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .style('fill', 'red')
  .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
  .attr('height', 70)
  .attr('x', function (d) {
    return xScale(d.title);
  })
  .attr('y', function (d) {
    return yScale.bandwidth() + 175;
  });
```

Generally, if you need a loop to enter elements in the DOM, you aren't using idiomatic d3. By avoiding the for loop to enter elements, the scaling also becomes easier because we aren't constantly updating it as we loop through the parent array. The scale domain and range only need to be set once.

Here's an updated [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZKJJj).

*Now, 2000 elements will result in very small rectangles, probably less than one pixel wide, and I'm not sure on why you are scaling the height of the bars as so, but these are different questions.*

Answer (score 3):

Nice problem description and CodePen - makes it easy to help you!

I have made a lightly modified version of yours [CodePen link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pYKqdx)

Basically, what happened was that for each iteration in your for loop, you would select the first x (in your case 20) matching `rect` elements. This means that each iteration, after the first, would just replace the data bindings to the same 20 `rect` elements with the current iteration's 20 data entries.

I have made two alterations to fix this:

1. Changed `svg.selectAll('rect')` to `svg.selectAll('.rect_${i}')`, which selects all elements with the corresponding class (`.rect_0`, `.rect_1`, etc.). Doing this prevents overwriting previous `rect` elements.
2. Added `+ xScale.range()[1] * i` to the callback function of `.attr('x')`. This moves each batch of 20 `rect` elements to the right, to make sure the `rect` elements are not drawn on top of each other.

Point 2 does, however, make for a very wide chart. In case you would like the rows to below each other, I have added functionality (in a comment) using the height of your `rect` elements to do this is.

Let me know if this helps you out!

Comment: Thank you! However this is not generating 2000 bars and it doesn't fit within container.

Comment: The first pass is actually the only one that adds elements, nothing is replaced, as the enter selection will be empty for each subsequent selection.

Comment: @AndrewReid, right you are - its just the data bindings that are replaced / updated to the same rects.

Comment: @EdgarKiljak, All 2000 bars are actually being drawn - most of them are just outside the SVG. Although it did strike me as odd that you would want such a wide visualization (one could always change the SVG dimensions), I thought to each his own :)